# Check if string is int

Tags: go

How can I check if a string value is an integer or not in Go?

Something like

```
v := "4"
if isInt(v) {
  fmt.Println("We have an int, we can safely cast this with strconv")
}
```

Note: I know that `strconv.Atoi` returns an error, but is there any other function to do this?

<s>The problem with `strconv.Atoi` is that it will return `7` for `"a7"`</s>

Comment: `strconv.Atoi` returns an error for "7a". http://play.golang.org/p/MTfQSOqPW3

Comment: You're right, I messed up in my testing

Comment: Alternative to prevent the error you can check for each index. This works for my use case. https://go.dev/play/p/bRMijt7nBMe

Answer (score 201, accepted):

As you said, you can use strconv.Atoi for this.

```
if _, err := strconv.Atoi(v); err == nil {
    fmt.Printf("%q looks like a number.\n", v)
}
```

You could use `scanner.Scanner` (from `text/scanner`) in mode `ScanInts`, or use a regexp to validate the string, but `Atoi` is the right tool for the job.

Comment: I tried to edit this, but somehow can't. It should be Printf not Println.

Comment: problem with this solution is that + and - characters in front of "v" value is also detected as valid number.

Answer (score 37):

this is better, you can check for ints upto 64 ( or less ) bits

strconv.Atoi only supports 32 bits

```
if _, err := strconv.ParseInt(v,10,64); err == nil {
    fmt.Printf("%q looks like a number.\n", v)
}
```

try it out with v := "12345678900123456789"

Answer (score 19):

You can use [`unicode.IsDigit()`](https://golang.org/pkg/unicode/#IsDigit):

```
import "unicode"

func isInt(s string) bool {
    for _, c := range s {
        if !unicode.IsDigit(c) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: Does - result in true for .IsDigit()? If not negative numbers would blow, lol.

Comment: Note this depends on what exactly you mean by 'int'. E.g. is ٢ an int? `IsDigit` says yes but `strconv.Atoi` fails to parse it https://play.golang.org/p/aLfLfwDgfr

Comment: Not entirely reliable as it would fail for negative numbers for instance. Atoi is probably safer

Answer (score 13):

You can use `govalidator`.

### Code

```
govalidator.IsInt("123")  // true
```

### Full Example

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    valid "github.com/asaskevich/govalidator"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Is it a Integer? ", valid.IsInt("978"))
}
```

Output:

```
$ go run intcheck.go
Is it a Integer?  true
```

Comment: You are pulling a whole struct validation library to do something that can be done with the go's standard library in two lines?

Comment: Might need more line if the value is larger than the max of int64?

Answer (score 10):

You might also use regexp to check this.

It can be a little overkill, but it also gives you more flexibility if you want to extend your rules.

Here some code example:

```
package main

import (
    "regexp"
)

var digitCheck = regexp.MustCompile(`^[0-9]+$`)

func main() {
    digitCheck.MatchString("1212")
}
```

If you want to see it running: https://play.golang.org/p/6JmzgUGYN3u

Hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 4):

This manually checks each CHAR to see if it falls between 0 and 9.

```
func IsDigitsOnly(s string) bool {
    for _, c := range s {
        if c < '0' || c > '9' {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Comment: It's nice to add a brief explanation of code just like it's nice to add comments to your actual code. Posting a code block by itself is frowned upon here. I know this is simple and self explanatory but that's why this answer was flagged as low quality.

Answer (score 3):

you can check if all runes are between 0 and 9

```
isNotDigit := func(c rune) bool { return c < '0' || c > '9' }
b := strings.IndexFunc(s, isNotDigit) == -1
```

Answer (score 1):

this might help

```
func IsInt(s string) bool {
    l := len(s)
    if strings.HasPrefix(s, "-") {
        l = l - 1
        s = s[1:]
    }

    reg := fmt.Sprintf("\\d{%d}", l)

    rs, err := regexp.MatchString(reg, s)

    if err != nil {
        return false
    }

    return rs
}
```

Answer (score 1):

be careful if your strings input could be in any length.

in cases where you have to check for monster strings length the `strconv` approach is useless. it will produce an `ErrRange` error.

for such scenarios:

```golang
s := strings.TrimSpace(val)

r := regexp.MustCompile(`^\d+$`)

isNum := r.Match([]byte(s))
```

Answer (score -1):

Most of the above posted solutions are neat and nice.

Below is a simple solution without using any library:

```
func IsNumericOnly(str string) bool {

    if len(str) == 0 {
        return false
    }

    for _, s := range str {
        if s < '0' || s > '9' {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Test cases

```
func TestIsNumericOnly(t *testing.T) {
    cases := []struct {
        name      string
        str       string
        isNumeric bool
    }{
        {
            name:      "numeric string",
            str:       "0123456789",
            isNumeric: true,
        },
        {
            name:      "not numeric string",
            str:       "#0123456789",
            isNumeric: false,
        },
    }

    for _, c := range cases {
        t.Run(c.name, func(t *testing.T) {
            assert.Equal(t, c.isNumeric, IsNumericOnly(c.str))
        })
    }
}
```