# How do i prevent this function from SQL Injection attack in Golang?

Tags: mysql, go, sql-injection

i'm new in golang.  i have problem when i write function this code for show detail data product. this code vulnerable to SQL injection. i'm use framework Gin,Gorm

```
func Show(c *gin.Context) {
    var product models.Product
    id := c.Param("id")

    if err := models.DB.First(&product, id).Error; err != nil {
        switch err {
        case gorm.ErrRecordNotFound:
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusNotFound, gin.H{"message": "Data not found"})
            return
        default:
            c.AbortWithStatusJSON(http.StatusBadRequest, gin.H{"message": err.Error()})
            return
        }
    }

    c.JSON(http.StatusOK, gin.H{"status": 200, "data": product})

}
```

how can I prevent this param id from SQL injection attack? or how can I validation only in parameter to prevent SQL injection?

Comment: As written, this code is not vulnerable

Comment: https://go.dev/doc/database/sql-injection

Comment: [Don't post pictures of text](/help/how-to-ask). Have the text in your post, with proper indentation and markdown.

Comment: But when i give single quote (') and trying running SQLmap to test SQL Injection attack at endpoint http://localhost/api/products/id<inject point>. this code still vulnerable, anything advice?

Comment: I think what you want is just check if id is a number - https://stackoverflow.com/a/22593449/2822041

Comment: Or if your id has a unique pattern, say a uuid, or an integer value, you can add a validation for that.

Answer (score 0):

This is s gorm query with inline condition and it is prone to sql injection.
As per the gorm documentation - [Retrieving objects with primary key](https://gorm.io/docs/query.html#Retrieving-objects-with-primary-key)

```
Objects can be retrieved using primary key by using Inline Conditions if the primary key is a number
```

Suppose the attacker used below input

```
id := "1=1;drop table products;"
```

The query will be translated as below

```
db.First(&product, id)
SELECT * FROM products WHERE 1=1;drop table products;
```

This can be simply prevented by a type check in the code

```
input,err := strconv.Atoi(id)

if err != nil {
    return error
}

db.First(&user, input)
```

Please follow the references from gorm for more info
[gorm security](https://gorm.io/docs/security.html)